# Rails Devise Signup: Separate Registration Form for User Type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a new signup page in Rails specific to an invitation URL such as this:

http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up?school=Elementary&principal=true

When a user invites their principal to sign up, I'd like a difference experience (new template that hides certain fields from the regular signup page).

I'm able to pass in the params into the form like this:

```
<%= f.text_field :school, :value => params[:school] %>
```

But I can't get logic in the view that hides certain inputs depending on the URL that the user comes in from. Essentially, I'm looking to fork **new.html.erb** into **newprincipal.html.erb**

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to accomplish it is checking value of the `principal` param in the controller and render a correct template based on it, e.g.:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def new
   render :new_principal if params[:principal] == true
  end

end
```

Ruby on Rails follows [convention over configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) paradigm, so unless `principal` param is set to `true` (or is not present) the default `new` template will be rendered. You can read more about layouts and rendering in [the official Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/layouts_and_rendering.html).

Comment: I'm using Devise for user management - would this be located in a new controller? And if so, how do I tell Devise to use this?

Comment: To tell Devise you need to update `config/routes.rb` file: `devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations:  'registrations'}`, after that you can create a new controller which should inherit from `Devise::RegistrationsController`, like in the above snippet, and you can extend Devise behaviour.

Comment: When I go to the signup page, I'm getting this error now: `ArgumentError in Registrations#new First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` and that first line contains: `<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>`

Comment: Try to put `super` in the first line of `new` method to inherit default behaviour from Devise method.

Comment: I am now able to get to the default signup page (new.html.erb) but when I hit this URL `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_up?principal=true` it's also bringing me to new.html.erb. Does rendering :new_principal need to be defined somewhere else?